# read tcp ip1->ip2: read: connection reset by peer in mac

Tags: tcp, connection, ip, peer

I'm getting the issue read ip1->ip2 read: connection reset by peer testing an App locally in my machine. I'm the only one facing this issue.

If I make ping over the first ip it responds ok.

With the second one ip2, I'm getting the issue:

```
    Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
    Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
    Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
    Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
    Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
    ....
```

I'm guessing that it is the cause of the issue. (What this two ip means? The ip1 and the ip2)
Is there any issue related with the mac or the security config?

Comment: The message "connection reset by peer" means that the other end nicely closed the connection. You typically get it when attempting to *write* at your end. To detect a close, you need to check the result of your read operation, it will return zero. If it does then you should also close the connection.

Comment: Sorry, do you know what means the Request timeout for icmp_seq over the second IP in this context?

Comment: The ping timeout is typically because the remote host doesn't answer. Or that a host along the route (including your local host) doesn't forward the ping packets.